# Connectivity error between openvz containers

Tags: routes, openvz

I have 2 HNs (each have 2 uplinks and 3 IP address ranges) with multiple containers on them.

HN1 and HN2 can reach all containers.
Containers from the same address range can reach each other.
But containers from different HNs cannot reach each other, if they have their IP addressses are from different ranges.

Network structure:

Cont1 (5.yy.yy.171) - HN1 (5.yy.yy.162, 85.xx.xx.51) - switch - HN2 (5.yy.yy.163, 85.xx.xx.52) - Cont2 (85.xx.xx.54)

Routes from HN2 (they're the same on HN1, only difference is its IP addresses):

```
# ip ru l
0:      from all lookup local
1:      from all lookup main
32748:  from 5.yy.yy.160/27 lookup 120
32749:  from 85.xx.xx.18/28 lookup 130
32750:  from 85.xx.xx.48/28 lookup 140
32766:  from all lookup 130
32767:  from all lookup default

# ip ro l table main: 
5.yy.yy.189 dev venet0  scope link
5.yy.yy.175 dev venet0  scope link 
85.xx.xx.54 dev venet0  scope link 
85.xx.xx.55 dev venet0  scope link 
85.xx.xx.48/28 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 85.xx.xx.52 
85.xx.xx.16/28 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 85.xx.xx.22 
5.yy.yy.160/27 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 5.yy.yy.163 

# ip ro l table 120: 
5.yy.yy.160/27 dev eth1  scope link  src 5.yy.yy.163
default via 5.yy.yy.161 dev eth1

# ip ro l table 130: 
85.xx.xx.16/28 dev eth0  scope link  src 85.xx.xx.22 
default via 85.xx.xx.17 dev eth0 

# ip ro l table 140: 
85.xx.xx.48/28 dev eth0  scope link  src 85.xx.xx.52 
default via 85.xx.xx.49 dev eth0
```

iptables is empty and defaulted to accept.

Any suggestions?

Comment: @Odedra: thanks for trying to improve posts, but please keep in mind that code spans (`like this`) are _not_ meant to highlight things that you think are important. In this case, it wasn't necessary. Code spans are only meant for formatting actual code within sentences.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy: thanks for such a good guidance, i will take care of it next time.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was pretty simple, i needed an asymmetric routing in addition to source-routing.

Setting rp_filter=0 solved my problem.